# AsyncTask updating UI

Tags: android-asynctask, android

So many hours trying to figure this out, I have read so many questions, forums, answers.. but it still will not update the UI.

My end goal is to take a search term from user, and send a httprequest to PHP scrip that replies with JSON. This works fine so I will not delve into it.

My problem is then updating the UI after this is done. I can get the HTTP results, but for now, I am just trying to update the UI with a basic string before implementing the big changes such as buttons with listeners etc with all the results. For now, just simple String addition to the UI.

The onPreExecute() adds a string to the UI and this works fine somehow, as implemented below.

The problem is in onPostExecute.. like I said, for now, just a String, to test (it will be a list or something eventually). It doesn't work at all, always throwing exception.

```
public class DisplaySearchActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;



private class updateUI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        listItems.add("Retrieving Results...");
                 // This actually works just like that
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
    final List<HashMap<String,String>> blist = httpSearch.search(message[0]); 
    return "It has done";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String b){
        Log.v("ok", "shane - "+ b);
        listItems.add("Business: "+ b);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //  final String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("input");
    final String message = "third+level";

    new updateUI().execute(message);

} // end onCreate


}
```

Here is the exception

```
03-15 13:38:41.190: V/ok(15732): shane - It has done
03-15 13:38:41.190: D/AndroidRuntime(15732): Shutting down VM
03-15 13:38:41.190: W/dalvikvm(15732): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4142a2a0)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at ie.whereis.DisplaySearchActivity$updateUI.onPostExecute(DisplaySearchActivity.java:34)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at ie.whereis.DisplaySearchActivity$updateUI.onPostExecute(DisplaySearchActivity.java:1)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-15 13:38:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it is being thrown by the line:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I just don't really understand what the adapter does, even after much reading. I don't know why the

```
listItems.add("Retrieving Results...");
```

in pre Execute works :S but the one in post does not.

Any help is so greatly appreciated.

---

Thank you, I have commented the solution. Apologies for not being able to deal out up votes. <15 karma

Comment: I had adapter instanciated twice it seems was the issue, and upon removing the final ArrayAdapter<String> as was suggested, the problem has been solved..

Thank you beautiful brains out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN your Oncreate replace

```
  final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
```

with

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
```

remove the  final ArrayAdapter

Comment: Oh my god this worked. Do you mind explaining why it did though? I don't really understand. p.s. I will mark correct as soon as I can..

edit: ohhh I had adapter created twice! Doh!

Comment: with  final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter in your oncreate u were creating a local variable adapter and the adapter instance variable declard at start of classs( which u were using in Asynctask OnpostExecute ) remained null :) .. Yea u got it in EDIT :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
DisplaySearchActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

to access adapter instance from `onPostExecute` method of `updateUI` class because you have declared `adapter=null`

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding instance field `adapter` in `onCreate` method.

Instead of

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
```

use

```
this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

your adapter is null . the one you set to list is bounded till oncreate() only . don't define again inside oncreate() . simply assing by
 `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the adapter will use the old data, you need to repass the modified list data before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

Firsty of all, why do you have your adapter declared as final? 
It looks like you are trying to modify the view when the activity is not visible. You should instantiate the asynctask to a member variable, and stop it in the onStop method of your Activity: myAsyncTask.cancel(true);